# Getting only integer numbers for pyswarm particles generations

Tags: python, integer

I am using pyswarm, I wonder if anyone has an idea how to change the setting to get only integer numbers for the swarm particles (x1, x2)!

```
from pyswarm import pso
def banana(x):
      x1 = x[0]     #  Get only integer number 
      x2 = x[1]     #  Get only integer number 
      return x1**4 - 2*x2*x1**2 + x2**2 + x1**2 - 2*x1 + 5
def con(x):
     x1 = x[0]
     x2 = x[1]
     return [-(x1 + 0.25)**2 + 0.75*x2]

lb = [-3, -1]
ub = [2, 6]

xopt, fopt = pso(banana, lb, ub, f_ieqcons=con)
```

Comment: Please define "get". Do you want to convert `x1` and `x2` to integers (if yes, is losing precision ok?), do you want the return value to be an integer or do you only want to allow integers as arguments?

Comment: Actually what I want is that the optimizer has to generate only integer number.  Basically, I want to get an only integer number of batteries (this obvious because getting a number of fraction of a battery is not a practical solution for the problem in hand!)  for each generation cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same problem today, I looked a bit on the code and found that this behavior is not handled at all. Also, there is no activity on the repository since 2015...

Moreover, it's not a good idea to map the initial real domain space to an integer space: all solutions between two integers will be computed with the same parameters.

Changing the objective function arguments implies you define an "error" value returned for non integers parameters (some kind of extreme value penalized by the optimization problem). But you will probably face with local optima this way.

So finally you might want to search for other libraries that implement PSO, or even try an implementation on the actual pyswarm code to support custom domains for particles.

EDIT: 
Here is a paper about PSO for integer programming: http://www.cs.uoi.gr/~kostasp/papers/C03.pdf